# Calling implicit controllers from PHPUnit test returning NotFoundHttpException:

Tags: php, api, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to test an API built in PHP using PHPUnit and when testing a route I am given the error InvalidArgumentException: Route [/list/create] not defined. I have set up my routes such that I am using an implicit controller where all routes can be defined within the controller file. Can anyone find a solution or provide some possible hints as to why this is happening?

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'App\Controllers\v2', 'prefix' => '2.0'), function()
{
    Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
    Route::controller('invite', 'InviteController');
    Route::controller('list', 'ListController');

    Route::post('/login','AuthController@login');
    Route::any('/logout','AuthController@logout');
});
```

ListTest.php

```
public function testList()
    {
        $user_id = getTestReceiverUserId();
        $response =
            json_decode($this->action(
                'POST',
                '/list/create',
                ['body' => array(
                    "name" => "open,shared",
                    "users" => array(array("user_id" => $user_id)),
                    "visibility" => "2",
                    "joinability" => "2",
                    "adminship" => "1",
                    "color" => "#2bc069"
                ),
                    'headers' => array('Auth' => getTestAuthSender())
                ])->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        $open_shared_list_id = $response['data']["list_id"];
        $list_key  = $response['data']["key"];
        $this->assertTrue(is_numeric($open_shared_list_id));
   }
```

ListController.php

```
Namespace App\Controllers\v1;
use BaseController;
use Timothylhuillier\LaravelMixpanel\Facades\LaravelMixpanel;
class ListController extends BaseController
{
    public function postCreate()
    {
        some code
    }
```

Comment: What's about `Route::post('/list/create', 'App\Controllers\v1\ListController @postCreate');` ?

Comment: Are you asking why I haven't listed the route in that way? If so, Laravel allows you to create implicit controllers in routes.php so you can define N number of actions pointing to routes in the controller file like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers